# How to hide text on mobile view within Static Block

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, static-block, html

I'm currently working with a static block on our website. I'm trying to hide certain pieces of texts within this block when viewed on mobile. I've come across some answers which use CSS. However, I don't have access to the CSS file of our website.

Therefore my question is: Is it possible to achieve this without adjusting the actual CSS file within the static block?

Comment: which version of magento you used?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have access to a CSS file, I only see two options.

1 - Embed a stylesheet at the top of the static block. While editing the static block in question, click the orange `Show/Hide Editor` button, insert your CSS solution mentioned above, and click save. Clear cache, and refresh page.

Here is a sample:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .myclass{display:none;}
}
</style>
```

2 - Add a style tag and desired CSS to the head section of every page using the `Miscellaneous Scripts` section in the Magento Admin.

- While logged into the Magento Admin, navigate to `System > Configuration > General > Design`. Expand the HTML Head section and paste your CSS solution mentioned above (including the style tags). Save the configuration. Clear cache, and refresh page. The same code sample above applies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Everytime I add this code to the static block, in the editor. It dissapears when I switch to wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Sometimes saving the block while the WYSIWYG editor is still hidden helps. If not, than I would recommend the 2nd suggestion.

Comment: So it doesnt work, yet. This is all the code on the page.

<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .myclass{display:none;}
}
</style>
<p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: left; padding-left: 80px;"><strong>✓ </strong>Betaal na ontvangst✓ </strong>Altijd een servicepunt bij u in de buurt<strong> ✓ </strong> Gratis verzending<strong><span style="float: right; padding-right: 80px;">✉ &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Schrijf je in voor de nieuwsbrief</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>

Comment: Well, `.myclass` is just a suggested selector - you need to change this to a selector of your choice. What are you trying to hide within that content? All of it?

Comment: Hmm okay. I'm trying to hide parts of the text. So if it's displayed on a fullscreen window it shows all the text. But when it's displayed on a phonescreen it should hide the first sentence.

My coding experience is probably too little to comprehend what's going wrong RN.

Comment: Try adding a class to the paragraph you want hidden, and use that as your selector: <style> @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { `.hide-on-mobile{display:none;}` } </style><p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p> <p `class="hide-on-mobile"` style="text-align: left; padding-left: 80px;"><strong>✓ </strong>Betaal na ontvangst✓ </strong>Altijd een servicepunt bij u in de buurt<strong> ✓ </strong> Gratis verzending<strong><span style="float: right; padding-right: 80px;">✉ &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Schrijf je in voor de nieuwsbrief</span></strong></p> <p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>

Comment: It Works! You're the best! Calling it a day for now. Thank you!

Comment: @Jordyb Great, glad it was helpful to you, don't forget to please accept the answer! To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.